# Selenium CTRL and click not working?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a row in a table by clicking it then moving to a second, holding shift or control and clicking that row to highlight both rows. I am having a problem with this using selenium webdriver and java. I can't see why this code doesn't work? It will select the first row then highlights the second also but when it clicks the second row the first is deselected? This is the code I am using:

```
  new Actions(driver)
            .moveToElement(selectConsentRow)
            .click()
            .moveToElement(secondRow)
            .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
            .click()
            .perform();
```

Comment: Your title says `CTRL` but your code says `SHIFT`, typo? Just a wonder. Looking at the code through, it appears to be 'correct'. I do notice you're missing a `.build()` before the `.perform()`. Have you tried with that?

Comment: Yeah I have tried it with both. Yes I have added .build() to see if that worked and it didn't. Any other suggestions cause I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not against using jquery, Then you can try this

```
driver.findelement(By.cssSelector(selectConsentRow_css_locator)).click();
   String script = "e = jQuery.Event('click');e.ctrlKey = true;    $('secondRow_Css_locator').trigger(e);";
   js.executeScript(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this with the following code:

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
    selectConsentRow.click();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    secondRow.click();
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: I think you should avoid doing this. This code will not work if you use a `RemoteDriver`.